# Allow the user to select a directory

Tags: python, tkinter, directory, filedialog

I know the command `filedialog.askopenfilename()`, but is there a way to let the user search for a directory instead of a single file?

Comment: do you know the name of the directory that you are trying to search ? What about the path of directory that you are trying to search ?

Answer (score 1):

I whink this is what you want

```
filedialog.askdirectory()
```

Comment: here is some docs on this module. enjoy http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/tkFileDialog